# Android write to internal storage

Tags: android, internal-storage

I tried to store a *.m4a file (a microphone recording) into a "public" directory, I mean into a directory like the ones of Telegram, WhatsApp accessible from the "My Files" app. I've tried to create my own directory:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
            + "/myDir/");

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
```

But the directory wasn't create.
I need to store files into a directory accessible when I plug my smartphone to the PC. What's wrong? Could someone help me?

Comment: did you put permission in manifest?

Comment: yes, both <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using one or more of the following:

1) Make sure you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

2) Use  `mkdirs()`  function

3) Use  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`  and try writing it in external storage

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly, I don't have external SD memory on my smarphone, so I need to store files into internal storage. I'm sure it is possible cause apps like Telegram, Whatsapp do it. Have you got an idea about that?

Comment: Maybe in that case, some part of your device's internal storage is exposed as external storage. Have a look at this link:
https://source.android.com/devices/storage/
If that is the case, the above steps should work

Comment: Really good!! I didn't know that some part of device's internal storage is exposed as external storage. You saved my day!! Thanks!!

Comment: you are welcome! :)  Did it solve your directory problem?

Comment: Hi can you give the sample code for saving data in internal storage.

Comment: @Tariqul Which Android version are you using?

Comment: Android 7.0 and 5.1.1 both android phone